# Как поместить форму xaml в папку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пара вопросов:

1. Создал папку `Forms` и закинул туда  `MainWindow.xaml`, в `App.xaml`
   прописал новый путь для `StartupUri`, но теперь ругается на
   пространство имен, как это исправить?
2. Что почитать, чтобы я больше
   не задавал таких вопросов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно поменять `namespace` у файла `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. Должно получиться так:

```
 namespace НазваниеПроекта.Forms
 {    
      public partial class MainWindow
      {
            //....
      }
 }
```

> Что почитать, чтобы я больше не задавал таких вопросов?

*Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed, Adam Nathan*